# How to get x and y values and function of xy pairs (H[x,y]) from Histogramlist?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, chemistry

So I have generated a set of random data points as shown below

```
sample1 = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0.4}, {1.2, 1.2}, 0], 250];
```

From the sample, I need to create a list of data points from the data above to fit into the NonlinearModelFit function. And because the NonlinearModelFit function requires the data to be structured in the form of a list of coordinate triples: e.g. {x, y, H[x,y]} where x and y are the pixel locations, and H[x,y] is the histogram value at that x-y coordinate, I need to generate data points.

The function I need to fit is:

```
A Exp[-((x - μ1)^2 + (y - μ2)^2)/(2 σ^2)]
```

Here is what I tried (so I first generated a list from the sample data points)

```
h1 = HistogramList[sample1, {-4, 4, 0.35}, "PDF"]
```

And then I tried to extract the x-y data points (but it wasn't very successful and I also do not know how to get the H[x,y] or function of x,y pairs as well)

```
h1xy = Table[{h1[[1, j]], h1[[2, j]]}, {j, 1, Length[h1[[1]]] - 1}]
```

Would anyone know how to do this that could help me out?

Comment: If your actual data is from a random sample from some distribution, then you definitely don't want to use `NonlinearModelFit` and you don't want to extract "data" from the construction of a `HistogramList`.  You want to do what @BobHanlon suggests.

Answer (score 4):

You can estimate the distribution from the data using either [`FindDistributionParameters`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDistributionParameters.html) or [`EstimatedDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EstimatedDistribution.html).

```
Clear["Global`*"]

dist1 = BinormalDistribution[{0, 0.4}, {1.2, 1.2}, 0];

SeedRandom[1234];

sample1 = RandomVariate[dist1, 250];
```

Your target distribution is

```
dist2 = BinormalDistribution[{μ1, μ2}, {σ, σ}, 0];
```

The estimate of the parameters of the target distribution is

```
param = FindDistributionParameters[
  sample1, dist2]

(* {μ1 -> 0.0574925, σ -> 1.10886, μ2 -> 0.272623} *)
```

Alternatively, you get the same distribution using `EstimatedDistribution`

```
EstimatedDistribution[sample1, dist2] === (dist2 /. param)

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sample1 = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0.4}, {1.2, 1.2}, 0], 250];
{{bins1, bins2}, hts} = HistogramList[sample1, {-4, 4, 0.35}, "PDF"]
f = {b1, b2} |-> Outer[List, Rest@b1, Rest@b2]; (* replace with any choice *)
xys = f[bins1, bins2];
Catenate@MapThread[Append, {xys, hts}, 2]  (* list of pts *)
```